# Radeon 13.1 legacy driver and xserver 1.13

Tags: 12.10, ati, radeon, fglrx

Is the latest radeon legacy driver compatible with xserver 1.13?
I have HD4xxx and HD5xxx video cards on my laptop. I want to install Ubuntu 12.10 but not sure if everything will be ok with legacy driver.

Answer (score 0):

It is not.

This does exist though:
https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx

You may want to uninstall your current drivers, upgrade to 12.10, then try that.

Comment: Thanks. I know about that solution and I don't like it. Just waiting when AMD releases new version of legacy driver. Are they going to do that at all?